# How can i init a new repo on top of an existing cloned one?

Tags: git, initialization, commit

Problem is simple:

I clone a repo that has been in development for long time, with the goal to use it locally (in this case it's [vue-starter](https://github.com/devCrossNet/vue-starter))

So this repo has remotes and a history, which i both want to discard (i want to start a clean state without any external history)

So i thought i should delete all the `.git` files, and `git init` a new repo.
did it, and it seems to have no effect.
then i thought i'll just make an init commit and work from there.

so i ran `npm install` and then had 44812 unstaged files which "commit" for around 20 minutes until it becomes unresponsive and freezes.

what is the "right" way to clone a project and start a new, local-only history (and commit tens of thousands of `npm install`ed files? all my googling didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: If you delete the `.git` folder, it's not a repository any more, but just an ordinary folder. Creating a new git repository with `git init` should initialize a new repository and let you add/commit files as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `.git` and doing a `git init` is not enough.

You need to make a first commit:

```
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
```

And set the upstream repo (if you need to push it back), an empty repo:

```
git remote add origin /url/remote/repo
```

Finally, push it back with `git push -u origin master`